# How adding hosts in CDH4

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have five server that free CDH4 install on them and services work very well. Today I want to add two hosts but it's failed.
this is log.

```
Refreshing package metadata...
BEGIN sudo apt-get update 
...
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4.0.0 Release 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4.1.4 Release 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4.0.0/contrib TranslationIndex 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4.1.4/contrib TranslationIndex 
Err http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4.0.0/contrib amd64 Packages 
Connection failed 
Err http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4.1.4/contrib amd64 Packages 
Connection failed 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4.0.0/contrib Translation-en_US 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4.0.0/contrib Translation-en 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4.1.4/contrib Translation-en_US 
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4.1.4/contrib Translation-en 
Fetched 2,965 kB in 24min 11s (2,042 B/s) 
W: Failed to fetch  http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/dists/precise- cdh4.0.0/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages Connection failed 

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.cloudera.com/cm4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cm/dists/precise-cm4.1.4/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages Connection failed 

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 
END (100)
```

this is not real problem. In the next command u see!

```
Installing oracle-j2sdk1.6 package...
BEGIN sudo apt-cache show oracle-j2sdk1.6 
E: No packages found 
END (100) 
remote package oracle-j2sdk1.6 is not available, giving up
```

and the rollback execute.
I think the real problem is Installing oracle-j2sdk1.6 but I don't know how figure out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install oracle-j2sdk1.6 manually and install completed. if your country not boycott you won't see this error.